# Registration crashes on Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to register my user and the tag say success. But I'm having an error and I don't know where the issue is.

This is my code:

```
// Registration in background
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
        try {
            String resu = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);
            if (Integer.parseInt(resu) == 3) {
                usernameExist = true;
            } else if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    registered = true;
                    // user successfully registered
                    // Store user details in SQLite
                    // Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in
                    // database
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                            json.getString(KEY_UID),
                            json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        if (usernameExist == true) {
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Username already existed");
        } else if (registered == true) {
            registerErrorMsg.setText("");
            Intent homepage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterSuccessActivity.class);
            homepage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homepage);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Error in registration
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Email address already existed");
        }
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

This is my logcat:

```
09-13 13:39:45.455: E/JSON(868): {"tag":"register","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"5051e1dac29176.90742708","user":{"name":"user","email":"user@gmail.com","created_at":"2012-09-13 21:38:34","updated_at":null}}
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:307)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:168)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.library.DatabaseHandler.addUser(DatabaseHandler.java:60)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.RegisterActivity$Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:150)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.RegisterActivity$Register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-13 13:39:46.225: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  ... 5 more
```

Can someone teach me so that I can learn? Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting your application and reinstalling it

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
```

indicates the error. Your SQLite that you opened is version 1, while the device has version 2.

You need to set the version of your SQLite to 2.
see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8223507/975959

Also, this tutorial might help
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: meaning i just set my database version to 2 or more can already?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with it, but from what I read, Yes. This error happens because your DB version is lower than the device's actual DB version. just set it to 2 (or higher, I assume) and it should work.